# The attach operation cannot continue because another object in this farm already contains the same ID

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, content-database, sql

My SQL DBA Team decided to change the SQL version and they did migration from one sql server to other sql server and when i tired to do add content database operation from central admin it gives this error

> The attach operation cannot continue because another object in this
>   farm already contains the same ID. Each object in a farm must have a
>   unique ID. In order to proceed with the attach operation you must
>   assign a new ID to this database. To attach this database with a new
>   ID, use the Mount-SPContentDatabase command with the
>   -AssignNewDatabaseId parameter. Note that if this new database and an existing database contain the same site collections, attaching this
>   database will likely result in orphaned site collections due to
>   conflicts between the two databases.

Comment: What version of SharePoint? What version of SQL? Does the new SQL have the same server and instance name? Did you detach the content databases from SharePoint prior to the SQL database move?

Comment: SharePoint 2010 SQL Server 13.0

Comment: SharePoint 2010 does not support SQL Server 2016. It supports a maximum of SQL Server 2012. Have your DBAs move your databases back to the old server.

Comment: Negative. It doesn't support SQL 2016 _at all_, doesn't matter the version level of the database itself. You need to have your DBAs roll back that change. If you and/or your DBAs need confirmation of this, you can either open a support ticket with Microsoft; or review https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ronalg/2014/03/24/sql-server-2014-and-sharepoint-supportability/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you did not detach the old databases (form old sql server) from SharePoint But you are trying to attach the content databases from new server which is why you are getting that error. You should follow these steps:

- Detach the current database from SharePoint which is pointing old SQL server
- Attach the Database to SharePoint from new SQL server.